# How to convert columns to rows in SQL Server without pivot and value is dynamic

Tags: sql, sql-server, row, identity-column

I have some values in rows like :

```
Month  | Product | SalesQty
-------+---------+---------
Jan-17 | ABC     |    3
Feb-17 | ABC     |    6
Apr-17 | ABC     |   19
```

But i want to show the some values in columns like:

```
Model| Apr-17 | May-17 | Jun-17 | Jul-17
ABC      1         2       12       0
BCS     212       12       12     112
```

Months must be generated dynamically. Static month will not help me in this situation.

Comment: Please explain what you have tried and why it failed. It will allow us to asses how much you know and how much you need to be explained.

Comment: Why can't you use pivot? Is there an upper boundary to the number of columns to be created?   is Dynamic SQL allowed?  Why are your doing data transformation at the database layer when it's a presentation issue?

Answer (score 2):

Why not Use [`pivot`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)? it is simpler than other solutions like `case` expression:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
PIVOT
(
  SUM(SalesQty)
  FOR Month IN([Apr-17] ,[May-17], [Jun-17], [Jul-17])
) AS p;
```

To do it dynamically you can use the same query with dynamic sql like this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);


select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +QUOTENAME(CONCAT(LEFT(datename(month, Month), 3),
                                         CAST(DATEPART(day, month) AS NVARCHAR(2))))
                      FROM table1
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @query = ' SELECT * 
FROM 
(
  SELECT product, SalesQty, 
     CONCAT(LEFT(datename(month, Month), 3), 
                CAST(DATEPART(day, month) AS NVARCHAR(2))) AS Month 
  FROM table1
) AS t
PIVOT
(
  SUM(SalesQty)
  FOR Month IN( ' + @cols + ' )
) AS p';

execute(@query);
```

[dynamic demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c2385/22)

---

If you don't want to use `PIVOT` then you can use `CASE` expression like this:

```
SELECT product,
  SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'Jan17' THEN SalesQty ELSE 0 END) AS Jan17,
  SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'Jan17' THEN SalesQty ELSE 0 END) AS Jun17,
  SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'Jan17' THEN SalesQty ELSE 0 END) AS Jul17
FROM 
(
  SELECT product, SalesQty, 
     CONCAT(LEFT(datename(month, Month), 3), 
                CAST(DATEPART(day, month) AS NVARCHAR(2))) AS Month 
  FROM table1
) AS t
GROUP BY Product;
```

Then to do this dynamically, you just need to replace the case expression part to by dynamic in the cols names variable.

Comment: @xQbert - Yes, I just noticed it, but may be he don't know he can make it dynamic. I can't see any reason why he wants to  do this without pivot. I will add alternative solution now.